# Temporarily disable a button in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am just playing with *flash cs5.5* (as3) and movieclips as buttons and have come across a problem.

I want to assign a listener to a `movieClip`, using `addEventListener`, this works fine:

```
myClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, menuEvent, false, 0, true);
```

I then use `myClip.mouseEnabled = false` to temporarily disable the button, but the button still works!

Any ideas why this is so?

Comment: Can you post all of your code? Because the two answers given here should disable the button, so that tells me that it's most likely not being disabled properly.

Comment: myClip is a simple movieClip (not a button) that I add the listener to and then immediately try to disable it, but it doesn't disable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myClip.mouseEnabled = false;
myClip.mouseChildren = false;
```

*This will ensure that not only the top level clip, but all of it's children will be mouse-disabled as well.*

Comment: This has worked....but why??!! There is another moviClip inside of myClip but why would it make this happen?

Comment: Because the child clip is still capable of dispatching a mouseEvent and since it's directly attached to the parent, it's going to basically make the listener in the parent fire.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is just `myClip.enabled = false`, if myClip is a button of course!

Comment: +1 Good point, didn't think of it actually being a Button object.